# How to get rid of mistakes in a merge commit and keep the right parts?

Tags: git, git-revert

Someone not familiar with git committed on his branch, and then made a merge commit with the `develop` branch. When merging, he:

1. resolved the conflicts by rewriting them completely
2. made change on several files that could be merged without conflicts
3. discarded other changes which should have been auto merged

Now I want to keep the part in 1 and 2, but revert the 3<sup>rd</sup> one, what should I do? Noted that his branch has been pushed to the remote so I hope that `reset` can be avoided.

What I have tried:

1. `git revert <commit-id> -m 1` and get back to the commit before merging
2. Try merging again but get told 'Already up to date.' and the changes discarded are still gone.

What I was expecting here should be the same as `git reset head^; git merge develop` but it seems that I do not understand `revert` correctly.

Comment: Please stop and read https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt It gives full instructions (or at least as full as you're going to get).

Comment: Thanks for the link and it does enlight me a lot, but I still feel it different from what I came across... What bothers me is that the merge commit contains both good changes and faulty discards, while the document describe how to deal with reverting a merge commit correctly...

Comment: Yes but it explains why your revert left you "up to date" and it shows some strategies for proceeding.

Comment: Yes, it explains my confusion though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no *right* answer to this particular problem.  There are only answers that leave a few problems, and answers that leave many problems.  The badness of each of these problems depends on your particular situation:

- For instance, using `git reset` to strip the merge, followed by a `git push --force`, creates problems for anyone else using the remote clone.  But perhaps only *one other person* is using that clone, and that one other person already knows what to do, or can be instructed as to what to do.

  In this case, the "badness" of stripping the bad merge and starting over is relatively small, especially since you can keep the good resolutions (although this requires manual work and a lot of Git knowledge).  Once you're done, nobody ever has to deal with the bad merge again, which leaves things in a nice state.
- But perhaps *many* people are using that remote repository, and stripping out the bad merge would cause irreparable damage.  In that case, the "badness" of stripping the bad merge is enormous, and you should use another strategy.

The main thing to remember is that a Git repository is, in the end, nothing more or less than a collection of *commits*.  The commits in the repository *are the history* and *are the repository*.<sup>1</sup>  So, whatever you end up doing, you will *add commits to the repository*.  To fix a bad merge commit, you must add more commits.

**These need not be merge commits.**  You can leave the existing merge in place, and simply remember it (or mark it—see `git notes`) as "bad, do not use".  You can then add ordinary (non-merge) commits that fix the problem.

**Each commit stores a full snapshot of every file.**  Commits *do not* contain differences from a previous commit.  So a bad merge commit is simply a commit with some files having the wrong contents.  A subsequent non-merge commit can store files with the right contents.

Your problem thus boils down to two parts:

- **You must decide whether or not to remove the bad merge.**  This is a value judgment, with no right answer.
- **You must come up with the corrected contents.**  This is a mechanical problem: how will you produce the correct files?  Here, Git can help.

Let me get a footnote out of the way, and then describe *how* Git can help.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is a mild overstatement: there may be `git notes`, although technically those are stored in commits anyway, and tags; and humans attach significance to branch names, which are also in the repository, but are rather ephemeral and should not be depended-on quite so heavily.

---

#### How Git performs a true merge

A true merge, in Git, is an operation on *three input commits.*<sup>2</sup>  The three commits include your *current commit*, as selected by your *current branch name* and the special name `HEAD`.  You give Git another commit on the command line: when you run `git merge other-branch-name` or `git merge hash-id`, Git uses this to locate the other *branch tip* commit.  For much more on how *branch tips* work, and how `HEAD` works, see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).  This site will also help understand the next part.

Given these two branch tip commits, Git now finds the third—or in some sense, *first*—of the three input commits on its own, using the *commit graph*.  Each ordinary, non-merge commit connects, *backwards*, to some earlier commit.  This series of backwards connections must eventually arrive at some *common starting point*, where the two branches last shared some particular commit.

We can draw this situation like this:

```
          I--J   <-- our-branch (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- their-branch
```

Our latest commit, which I've drawn as commit `J`, points backwards to some earlier commit(s), which I've drawn as commit `I`.  Their latest commit `L` points backwards to some earlier commit `K`.  But then `I` and `K` point backwards to some commit—here, `H`—that's on *both branches at the same time*.  [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/) has a lot more about how this works, but for our purposes here, we need only see that Git finds commit `H` on its own, and that it's on both branches.

When we run `git merge` with commit `J` as our commit—which Git calls `--ours` or `HEAD` or the *local* commit—and commit `L` as their commit—Git calls this it either `--theirs`, or the *remote* commit, typically—Git finds commit `H` as the merge base.  Then it:

1. Compares the snapshot *in* commit `H` to the snapshot in our commit `J`.  This finds out what files *we* changed, and what changes we made to those files.
2. Compares the snapshot in `H` to the one in `L`.  This finds out what files *they* changed, and what changes they made to those files.
3. *Combines the changes*.  This is the hard-work part.  Git does this combining using simple text-substitution rules: it has no idea which changes really should be used.  Where the rules allow, Git makes these changes on its own; where the rules claim that there is a conflict, Git passes the conflict on to us, for us to fix.  In any case, Git *applies* the combined changes to the snapshot in the starting commit: merge base `H`.  That keeps our changes while adding theirs.

So, if the merge goes well on its own, *Git* will make a new merge commit `M`, like so:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- our-branch (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- their-branch
```

New commit `M` has a snapshot, like any commit, and a log message and author and so on just like any commit.  The only thing that's special about `M` is that it links back not just to commit `J`—our commit when we started—but also to commit `L`, the commit whose hash ID we told `git merge` about (either using the raw hash ID, or using the name `their-branch`).

If we have to fix up the merge ourselves, we do that and run `git add` and then either `git commit` or `git merge --continue`, to make merge commit `M`.  When we do this, we have full control over what goes into `M`.

---

<sup>2</sup>This is the kind of merge that results in a *merge commit*, i.e., a commit with two parents.  Git can also perform what it calls a *fast-forward merge*, which is not a merge at all and produces no new commit, or what it calls an *octopus merge*, which takes more than three input commits.  Octopus merges have certain restrictions, which means they do not apply to this case.  True merges can involve making a *recursive* merge, which complicates the picture as well, but I'm going to ignore this case here: the complications are not directly relevant to what we'll be doing.

---

#### Redoing the bad merge

Our situation here is that we started with:

```
          I--J   <-- our-branch (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- their-branch
```

Then someone—presumably not us —ran `git merge their-branch` or equivalent, got merge conflicts, and resolved them incorrectly and committed:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- our-branch (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- their-branch
```

To *re-perform the merge*, we just need to check out / switch to commit `J`:

```
git checkout -b repair <hash-of-J>
```

for instance, or:

```
git switch -c repair <hash-of-J>
```

to use the new (since Git 2.23) `git switch` command.  Then we run:

```
git merge <hash-of-L>
```

To get the two hash IDs, we can use `git rev-parse` on merge commit `M`, with the funky `^1` and `^2` syntax suffixes; or we can run `git log --graph` or similar and find the two commits and see their hash IDs directly.  Or, if the name `their-branch` still finds commit `L`, we can run `git merge their-branch`.  Git just needs to locate the correct commit.

Git will, at this point, repeat the merge attempt it tried earlier, following exactly the same rules.  This will produce exactly the same conflicts.  Our job is now to fix up these conflicts, but this time, we do it correctly.

If we like the resolution that someone else made in commit `M`, we can ask `git checkout` (all versions of Git) or `git restore` (Git 2.23 and later) to extract the resolved file that the other person put in commit `M`:

```
git checkout <hash-of-M> -- <path/to/file>
```

for instance.  Even if we don't like the entire resolution, we can still do that and then fix up the file and run `git add`; only if we don't like *any* of the resolution, and want to do the entire fixing-up ourselves, do we *have* to do the entire fixing-up ourselves.

One way or another, though, we just fix up each file and `git add` the result to tell Git that we have fixed up the file.  (The `git checkout hash -- path` trick makes it so we can skip the `git add` step in some cases, but it won't hurt to run `git add` anyway either.)  When we're all done, we run `git merge --continue` or `git commit` to finish this merge: the result is a new merge commit `M2` or `N`, on our new branch `repair` or whatever we called it when we created it:

```
          I--J-----M2   <-- repair (HEAD)
         /    \   /
...--G--H      M /  <-- our-branch
         \    /_/
          K--L   <-- their-branch
```

We can now `git checkout our-branch`, which lands us on commit `M`, and grab files directly from `repair`:

```
git checkout our-branch
git checkout repair -- path/to/file1
git checkout repair -- path/to/file2
...
```

and then we're ready to `git commit` to make a new commit `N`.  Or, we can en-masse grab *every* file from `M2`:

```
git checkout repair -- .
```

and run `git status`, `git diff --cached`, and/or `git commit` at this point, depending on how sure we are we got this all right.

The result of the above is:

```
          I--J-----M2   <-- repair
         /    \   /
...--G--H      M-/--N   <-- our-branch (HEAD)
         \    /_/
          K--L   <-- their-branch
```

and we can now delete branch name `repair` entirely: commit `N` is just "magically fixed".

If we intend to *keep* commit `M2`, we can use `git merge` to merge `repair` into `M`.  We might want to run `git merge --no-commit` so that we gain full control: this will stop `git merge` from making the actual commit yet, so that we can inspect the snapshot that's about to go in to the new merge.  Then the final `git merge --continue` or `git commit` makes `N` as a new merge commit:

```
          I--J-----M2   <-- repair
         /    \   /  \
...--G--H      M-/----N   <-- our-branch (HEAD)
         \    /_/
          K--L   <-- their-branch
```

and once again we can delete the name `repair`; it no longer adds anything of value.

(I'd generally just make a simple non-merge fixup commit myself, rather than another merge.  The merge base for making `N` *as* a merge is both commits `J` and `L`, which means Git will do a recursive merge unless we specify `-s resolve`.  Recursive merges tend to be messy and have weird conflicts sometimes.)

#### If there have been commits since the bad merge

Commits that occur *after* bad-merge-`M` just need their changes carried forward into what I have drawn above as final commit `N`.  How you go about achieving that is not really terribly important, though some ways may have Git do more of the work for you.  The thing to remember here is what I said earlier: in the end, it's the *commits in the repository* that matter.  That includes both the graph—the backwards-looking connections from commit to earlier commit—and the snapshots.  The graph matters to Git itself, as it is how `git log` works and how `git merge` finds the merge base.  The snapshots matter to *you*, as they are how Git stores the *content* that you care about.

Comment: How you draw these git diagrams? is there any tool available or normal text formatting by yourself?

Comment: @hackwithharsha: by hand - I have had a fair bit of practice at this point. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I manage to fix it myself. I post the solution in case someone lucky came across similar situation.

1. Checkout a new branch from `develop`, let's call it `fix`
2. Merge the faulty branch into `fix`, and pick the right parts and discard the wrong parts
3. Merge `fix` into the faulty branch because I want to keep the branch clean

It seems easy, why can it take me so much time to come up with the solution...?